# Optimize ruby on rails SQL queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**Update start**

This problem was with rendering a form for each project, not with SQl queries. To optimize I will add the form as needed with javascript.

It seems like I didn't read the miniprofiler log correct. I apologize, but leave the question for others that might have similar questions.

**Update end**

I am using miniprofiler to find bottlenecks in my app. And I found one!

```
SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON 
"projects"."id" = "memberships"."project_id" WHERE 
"memberships"."user_id" = 1 AND (active = 't')   
1059.50 ms  
Rendering: projects/_index — 1023.18 ms
```

It is finding 185 projects in 1 whole second.

**How can I make a query that does this more efficient?**

I have this in my projects_controller index

```
@projects = current_user.projects.is_active
```

The is_active scope in the projects model

```
scope :is_active, where(["active = ?", true])
```

The projects and users has a many to many relationship, with a membership join table

The membership model

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id,:user_id,:created_at,:updated_at
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

The membership table

```
def self.up
    create_table :memberships do |t|
      t.integer :project_id
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :memberships, [:project_id, :user_id], :unique => true
end
```

I am running this in the production environment on the local computer with postgreSQL as the database

Adding explain by Jiří Pospíšil request. In the console it does not seem to be slow at all. This explain is done in development. Have the same problem there

```
User.first.projects.is_active.explain
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
  Project Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "projects"."id" = "memberships"."project_id" WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = 1 AND (active = 't')
  EXPLAIN (0.2ms)  EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "projects"."id" = "memberships"."project_id" WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = 1 AND (active = 't')
 => "EXPLAIN for: SELECT \"projects\".* FROM \"projects\" INNER JOIN \"memberships\" ON \"projects\".\"id\" = \"memberships\".\"project_id\" WHERE \"memberships\".\"user_id\" = 1 AND (active = 't')\n0|0|1|SEARCH TABLE memberships USING INDEX index_memberships_on_user_id (user_id=?) (~10 rows)\n0|1|0|SEARCH TABLE projects USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)\n"
```

The view

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
<li class="tab_list" id="project_<%= project.id.to_s %>"> 
  <div class="tab_list_text"><%= link_to project.name, project_path(project) %></div>
  <span class='open_project_update button edit' id="project_update" data-id="<%= project.id %>" data-object="project" title="Edit project">Edit</span> 
  <div class="dialog_form" id="project_update_<%= project.id %>_form" title="Update project" style="display:none;">
      <%= form_for(project) do |f| %>
      <ul>
      <li><%= f.label :name %><%= f.text_field :name %></li>
      <li><%= f.label :description %><%= f.text_field :description %></li>
      <li><%= f.label :due %><%= f.text_field :due, :value => project.due.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), :id => "date_project_#{project.id}"  %></li>
      <li><%= f.label :customer_id %><%= f.select(:customer_id, @customers.map {|customer| [customer.name, customer.id]}, {:include_blank => 'None'})%></li>
      <li><%= f.submit 'Save', :class => 'submit' %></li></ul>
      <% end %>
  </div>
  <a class="activate_project button" data-object="project" data-id="<%= project.id.to_s %>">Archive</a>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you run the query with explain?

Comment: I have updated the question with the explain

Comment: Project load is only taking 2.3ms.  The time to render projects/_index is 1 second.  The query is not your bottleneck.  Or maybe I'm wrong... I've been up all night.

Comment: Could you show me the view the is being rendered and the controller, if possible?

Comment: The query takes place when the view gets rendered. It's lazy loading. Updating with view code.

Comment: Did you check how long does it take when you pass raw sql request directly to a db console? If it works much faster, the problem is in AR/AV definitions, if not - just think about how to optimize data structure, app logic and increase power of DB machine.

Comment: And never do db request within ActionView environment. All db requests have to be made before - in controller.

Comment: I didn't. It was a rendering problem. I found it when I was posting the views here. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Project load is only taking 2.3ms. The time to render projects/_index is 1 second. The query is not your bottleneck.

Based on your comment, you say that you're lazy loading the relationships.  Make sure that you eager load the relationships by using `includes`.

For example:

```
@user.projects.is_active.includes(:some_association).includes(:another_association)
```

`includes` will cause the relationship to be eager loaded.

If you're iterating over a list of users, to get the active projects, you'll need to do something like:

```
User.includes(:projects)
     .merge(Project.is_active)
     .includes(projects: :some_other_association)
```

It is good practice to not put DB queries in your views.  Try to do that via the controller.

Comment: + 1 agreed. :includes would be faster and don't init DB request in the view. ActionView - is one big bottleneck of whole Rails. imho.

Comment: +1 agreed Use includes whenever I can. Turns out the query was OK. It was a rendering problem. I have updated question. Meta; Should I answer my own question and accept it. No one could answer this correct based on my question. This is a really good answer even though it didn't solve the problem

Comment: You can probably just answer your own question.  I briefly looked at the view, and nothing stood out at me on first glance.

Comment: If I remove the form_for I am down at 100ms. I edited you answer with your first comment on top. When approved I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You know, now that I have looked at it again, you probably want to run the `@customers.map` before you enter that loop or in the controller.  That may be slowing you down, especially if you have a lot of customers and/or projects.

Comment: Yes I was also looking at that too. Thank you too, sir! No get some sleep!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a new released [gem 'query_optimizer'](https://rubygems.org/gems/query_optimizer)
now .
query_optimizer is the best gem for optimizing query in rails for has_many and belongs_to relationship two tables

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Yes the link is related to question user can get all project and its memberships in single query as QueryOptimizer.optimize_query(Project,Membership)

Comment: More accurate QueryOptimizer.optimize_query(Project,Membership).select {|user| user["users_id"]  == "#{current_user.id}" }

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has mentioned it yet, the **[bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet)** is excellent for identifying pages in your apps where you inadvertently created N+1 queries (your specific case) that could benefit from **eager loading** (using `includes` as well-outlined in the accepted answer) and **counter-caching**.

This great [post](http://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/) outlines both the problems and solutions in simple, clear language as well as giving an intro to using the bullet gem.  There is also a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/372-bullet) on implementing **bullet** though I have not gone through it.